# How to make Visual Studio throw exceptions into the NUnit gui?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit

I'm new to C# and I am confused with the way NUnit and Visual Studio interact regarding exceptions.

From using it before, I remember that exceptions were thrown into the NUnit Gui "Errors and failures" tab, making the tests red - that is what I need now.

Now even Assert.Fail returns me to the VS window.

My setup is:

- VS 2010 **Express**, NUnit 2.5.10
- Main project is a 'Class Library' output
- Launcher project is a starup project, 'Windows Application' output and has a reference to the main project
- I run the tests from Visual Studio pressing 'debug' (this brings up the NUnit GUI window)
- Launcher code:

> ```
> namespace Launcher
> {
>     class Launcher
>     {
>         [STAThread]
>         static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             NUnit.Gui.AppEntry.Main(new[] { "MainProject.dll" });
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I know that I can open NUnit and then my dll and it will show exceptions inside NUnit window.

What I want is to press Debug and have NUnit to execute tests that I select, throw exceptions into NUnit window and make me able to set breakpoints - that worked before!

Comment: I'm guessing that your not running the nunit gui?  Why not setup the gui to open up your test.dll that way?

Comment: The gui is being opened automatically with my dll

Comment: Why do you need this Windows application? Just use NUnit GUI as executable for debugging.

Comment: I am not sure this should be working in the first place. Somehow when starting your program in debug mode in VS, I would expect VS to react when an exception is thrown...

Comment: Hi Alex, I need to press 'Debug' and have NUnit GUI pick my library up. If you would advise how this can be done in a better way, I'd be grateful.

Comment: On the project's Debug tab you can select which application to run on debug, that can be NUnit GUI

Comment: Dmitry, I don't have 'Start external program' on the debug tab, only 'Command line arguments'

Answer (score 4):

Open up Nunit, 
Go to File --> Open project
Navigate to the .dll of your unit test project, this should open up all your tests.

From here you can run all the test etc.
You can setup nunit to run test everytime you rebuild your project (so ctrl-shift-b).  No need to always press the debug button.

If you want to debug your test,
(in vs2010), go to debug --> attach to process --> select nunit-agent.exe,
that should allow you to hit your breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I have figured the first part by myself already, and it's not what I want.
Regarding 'attach to process' - I don't have this menu option at all.
What I want is to press Debug and have NUnit to execute tests that I select, throw exceptions into NUnit window and make me able to set breakpoints - that worked before!

Comment: I used to do that but it looks like in vs2010 but got into issues.  Try this link - http://frater.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/debugging-nunit-tests-under-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Lareau, thanks for your answer, but I can debug tests just fine in my current config. The only thing that is not working is that exceptions are not thrown into NUnit GUI.

Comment: (debug --> attach to process) is not available in the Express Edition. Doing something along the lines of NUnit.Gui.AppEntry.Main(...) is needet there.